How to enable component in Android Settings app using ADB shell

Here is what I am trying to achieve, I'm trying to derive an adb shell command that allows me to toggle these switches inside the settings app programmatically. I've used dumpsys to figure out these component names (at least that's what I believe).
fuxi:/ # dumpsys package com.android.settings
Service Resolver Table:
  Non-Data Actions:
      android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE:
        47bc38b com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowLayout filter 6c8cc68 permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        236e881 com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$GPUProfiling filter fe7d26 permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        7e10d67 com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ForceRTL filter 1924714 permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        a688bbd com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$AnimationSpeed filter a4545b2 permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        4671903 com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$WinscopeTrace filter 4d6c080 permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        11726b9 com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$SensorsOff filter be0afe permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        6b8425f com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$WirelessDebugging filter 52764ac permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        b7a7575 com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowTaps filter 6bd90a permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        1c8a57b com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$DesktopMode filter cfc1f98 permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"
        89f3f1 com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowRefreshRate filter 767bd6 permission android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE
          Action: "android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"

Packages:
  Package [com.android.settings] (225ab18):
    appId=1000
    sharedUser=SharedUserSetting{e7ec628 android.uid.system/1000}
    pkg=Package{c61500b com.android.settings}
    codePath=/system_ext/priv-app/Settings
    resourcePath=/system_ext/priv-app/Settings
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/system_ext/priv-app/Settings/lib
    extractNativeLibs=true
    primaryCpuAbi=arm64-v8a
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    cpuAbiOverride=null
    versionCode=34 minSdk=34 targetSdk=34
    minExtensionVersions=[]
    versionName=14
    usesNonSdkApi=true
    splits=[base]
    apkSigningVersion=3
    flags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP KILL_AFTER_RESTORE ]
    privateFlags=[ PRIVATE_FLAG_ACTIVITIES_RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE_VIA_SDK_VERSION ALLOW_AUDIO_PLAYBACK_CAPTURE DEFAULT_TO_DEVICE_PROTECTED_STORAGE DIRECT_BOOT_AWARE PARTIALLY_DIRECT_BOOT_AWARE PRIVILEGED SYSTEM_EXT PRIVATE_FLAG_ALLOW_NATIVE_HEAP_POINTER_TAGGING ]
    forceQueryable=false
    queriesIntents=[Intent { act=com.android.setupwizard.action.PARTNER_CUSTOMIZATION }]
    dataDir=/data/user_de/0/com.android.settings
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    usesLibraries:
      org.apache.http.legacy
      com.qti.extphone.extphonelib
    usesOptionalLibraries:
      androidx.window.extensions
      androidx.window.sidecar
    usesLibraryFiles:
      /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar
      /system_ext/framework/extphonelib.jar
    timeStamp=2009-01-01 08:00:00
    lastUpdateTime=2009-01-01 08:00:00
    installerPackageName=null
    installerPackageUid=-1
    initiatingPackageName=null
    originatingPackageName=null
    packageSource=0
    appMetadataFilePath=null
    signatures=PackageSignatures{f549ee8 version:3, signatures:[92d864b3], past signatures:[]}
    installPermissionsFixed=false
    pkgFlags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP KILL_AFTER_RESTORE ]
    privatePkgFlags=[ PRIVATE_FLAG_ACTIVITIES_RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE_VIA_SDK_VERSION ALLOW_AUDIO_PLAYBACK_CAPTURE DEFAULT_TO_DEVICE_PROTECTED_STORAGE DIRECT_BOOT_AWARE PARTIALLY_DIRECT_BOOT_AWARE PRIVILEGED SYSTEM_EXT PRIVATE_FLAG_ALLOW_NATIVE_HEAP_POINTER_TAGGING ]
    apexModuleName=null
    User 0: ceDataInode=5887 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false distractionFlags=0 stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false
      installReason=0
      firstInstallTime=2009-01-01 08:00:00
      uninstallReason=0
      disabledComponents:
        com.android.settings.Settings$LanguageAndInputSettingsActivity
        com.android.settings.SetupFingerprintSuggestionActivity
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$AnimationSpeed
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$WinscopeTrace
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowLayout
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$GPUProfiling
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowTaps
        com.android.settings.homepage.DeepLinkHomepageActivity
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowRefreshRate
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$SensorsOff
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ForceRTL
        com.android.settings.search.SearchStateReceiver
      enabledComponents:
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$DesktopMode
        com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$WirelessDebugging
        com.android.settings.Settings$ConnectedDeviceDashboardActivity
        com.android.settings.Settings$PowerUsageSummaryActivity
        com.android.settings.Settings$WifiDisplaySettingsActivity
        com.android.settings.Settings$BluetoothSettingsActivity
        com.android.settings.Settings$DevelopmentSettingsDashboardActivity
        com.android.settings.SetupRedactionInterstitial
        com.android.settings.Settings$WifiSettingsActivity
        com.android.settings.WebViewImplementation
        com.android.settings.Settings$UserSettingsActivity
        com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity
        com.android.settings.Settings$LanguageSettingsActivity

I am assuming by enabling this components via pm enable com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowLayout should get the job done. Unfortunately, it gives me this error.
fuxi:/ $ su
fuxi:/ # pm enable com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowLayout

Exception occurred while executing 'enable':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles does not exist in com.android.settings
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSettings(PackageManagerService.java:4035)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-$$Nest$msetEnabledSettings(PackageManagerService.java:0)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.setComponentEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:5962)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runSetEnabledSetting(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2489)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:269)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:6474)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1097)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:914)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4403)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:6458)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1363)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1304)

Is it permission issue? I have root access for shell.
For reference, this is the source code for the relevant part. Yes, I'm trying to do this on a custom rom https://github.com/AOSPA/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/uvite/src/com/android/settings/development/qstile/DevelopmentTilePreferenceController.java

My bad, first time posting

Shell must be treating $ShowLayout as a variable. Put the component name in quotes or escape the $ sign. pm enable 'com.android.settings/.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$ShowLayout'

@IrfanLatif This is exactly it! I can't believe I missed this. I need to escape the '$' in order for it to work. Thanks
